# Failed to clear temp storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

I'm getting this error in console. I have a script name script.js which makes ajax calls to retrieve data from php.

Any idea why?

Here's my jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var loading = false;
  var docHeight = $(window).height();

  $('.timeline').css({minHeight: docHeight});

  function get_tl_post() {

    if (loading==false) {

      loading = true;

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"timeline.php",
        data:"data=instagram",
        beforeSend:function(){
           $('.loader').fadeIn("slow");
        },
        complete:function(){
          loading = false;
          $('.loader').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        success:function(data) {
          if(data=="error")
          {
            get_tl_post();
          }
          $(data).hide().appendTo(".timeline").fadeIn(1000); 
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      get_tl_post();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can we see the script?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz  Sure, added in description. Any idea?

Comment: Instead of `if (data=="error"){ get_tl_post(); }`, try `console.log(data)` & see what's logged out in your browser's console. You might be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you running this page from a web server? Also if there's an error it will keep running the function. You should possibly reconsider that recursion. Possibly adds counter so it only attempts to run for a set amount of times.

Comment: Shouldn't your $(document).ready(function() { end with ...)}; I don't see that here. It looks like a simple recursion problem. I think get_tl_post() may be getting called over and over again.

Comment: Are you using Indexed DB heavily in your application?

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 8):

#### This is Due to Network Mapping of your resources.

*In other words, you might have **added workspace folder** in your chrome dev tools.
Now when you are trying to make changes in some files it makes the Request to the File-System. This works fine for a while. However in some scenarios you remove your network mapping.*

Then when you trying to open that web page on the browser, it might or might not ask for remapping of network resources and still try to update the File System.
And that's when you get this error.
There is nothing wrong with your script.

Now the only solution to this could be Removing cache, then restarting System.
If the problem still persist, you can simply re install chrome and this should be fixed.

Moreover, sometimes network mapping can cause several other issues as well.
For example, making the CSS file size to whooping 75MB or above. So you have to take precautions when playing with network mapping.

> Optionally if you are on Mac...  or Even on Windows and have sh
> commands available.

```
sudo find / -type f -size +50000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

Hit this in your Terminal to find out the culprit individual file which is over 50MB. you could then remove them.

> Note : What the above command does it, it will find all the individual files which are more than 50MB and print them on your terminal one by one.

Answer (score 2):

If I was to guess I would say your `timeline.php` script is always returning "error" so you are making too many calls recursively and the browser blocks them.

Try to eliminate the recursive function call and see if that will fix the problem.

Remove the following 3 lines  and try again:

```
if (data == "error")
{
    get_tl_post();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ajax call fails for some reason, this could lead to too many recursive calls of the `get_tl_post();`.

I suggest that you use the `error` property for error handling, and to avoid situations of recursively calling your function. An idea could be to set a policy like "if the request failed/data are with errors, wait for an amount of time, then retry. If X retries are made, then show an error code and stop requesting".

Below is an example of *untested* code, in order to show you the idea:

```
var attempts = 0;
$.ajax({
  //Rest of properties
  success: function(data) {

    if(data == "error") {
      if(attempts < 3) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          get_tl_post();
          ++attempts;
        }, 2000);
      } else {
        //output failure here.
      }

    }

    //Rest of code....
  }
});
```