# Failed to clear temp storage: SecurityError in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, svg, google-chrome-devtools

Is there anyone who have seen this error?

> Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

What I am doing now is piping svg files into dist/static folder using gulp and rendering some svg images on the map.

Last time I clicked the map(svg images are map markers) so many times in a row and then chrome threw this error

After I got this, I can't find those svg resources in my Sources tab anymore. But I can see those svg files are successfully piped into the dist/static folder on my local directory.

I tried this

1) Deleted chrome and reinstalled

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google`
- `~/Library/Caches (deleted all the google data)`
- `~/Library/Preferences (deleted all the google data)`
- `~/Library/Google`

2) Created a directory with different name and piped svg files to that folder

But still did not work at all.
Weird thing is 2 svg filed in different directory is working.
(My svg files(map markers) were rendered well before I got this error.)

Is there anyone who resolved this problem?

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+F5 to refresh browser

Comment: Here's a [stackoverflow of the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358446/failed-to-clear-temp-storage).